# Why isn't my question getting any attention even after the bounty?

Tags: discussion

[Why does fat make chapati/parathas/pooris remain soft?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/43623/6168)

I wish to know the problem. Is that question ill formed OR unclear OR not much useful?

No one has asked or said anything comments, not many up or down votes, not many answers.

What's the problem that I should attempt to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it's just that no one who's seen it has a better answer to offer. Bounties do try to make sure that our users see the question, but they unfortunately don't change whether people actually have an answer!

(I went ahead and edited it for grammar and clarity, but I'm not sure that was the issue.)

Comment: but it hasn't many up or down votes which tells me that users aren't finding the question of much use? may be because it is an Indian cuisine and majority of people here are western?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius People just don't vote on questions very frequently here. Look at the recent questions: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest - going back to the time your question was originally posted, the vast majority have 0-3 votes. Yours is right in that range. Sure, it has a bounty, so maybe a few more people saw it, but most of our regular voting users see nearly all the questions. And of course, it was a bit unclear before I edited it, so maybe that stopped an upvote or two. But really, I think you're reading too much into the voting.

Comment: okay, thanks for response and the edit.

Comment: +1 @Jefromi for "regular voting users see nearly all the questions" it's not a difficult stack to keep up with. Honestly, I only vote on questions I find to be truly exceptional.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald The point here was about answers, not voting. Your voting standards are up to you, of course, but I'd really encourage you to vote not just on exceptional things. The hover text says "useful and clear", not "exceptional" - and there's even a gold badge for keeping your question voting percentage high to really make it clear we value those votes. Upvoting questions rewards people who take the time to post questions, which is what keeps the site alive.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind @Jefromi